# Insertion and searching time complexity AVL Tree

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, avl-tree

I know AVL tree's search and insertion time complexity is supposed to be O(logn), but with the tree I built, when I make a graph with the times it takes to do N operations, it ends up beeing a N graph. This is the graph I get, Y is the time in seconds and X is the number of operations (both insert and search) [image: y = time, x = number of operations]

Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: It would help to see how you call your tree operations, and how you time them, to produce this graph. Also, does the graph still look linear for larger values?

Comment: "Is this supposed to happen?" In short: no. You likely have a performance bug. Try testing up to larger number of operations to double check.

Answer (score -1):

Big-o notation is only an accurate estimate if n tends to infinity. Assuming your AVL tree is implemented correctly, the explanation for this could be the constants ignored by the big-o notation.

It's likely that the graph would start to flatten if the number of operations increase.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).